# VBScript Excel ADO connection: Get value using column alias in SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript, ado

In following code, I can get the count from excel using

`objTempRecordset.Fields.Item(0).Value`

However, I want to use column name alias in SQL.
i.e.

```sql
sSQL = "Select Count(*) AS RecCount FROM [NELimits$] A WHERE A.Type = 'A' AND A.ID = " &Chr(39) & "R001" & Chr(39)
```

and I want to get the result using:

`objTempRecordset.Fields.Item("RecCount").Value`

I also tried `objTempRecordset.Fields.Item("_Count(*)_").Value` but no luck

Can someone please let me know how to use column name alias in this case?

Note: Excel has 2 columns 
ID: with values such as "R001", "R002"
Type: with values such as "A","B","C"

Sample code:

```vb
sSQL = "Select Count(*) FROM [NELimits$] A WHERE A.Type = 'A' AND A.ID = " &Chr(39) & "R003" & Chr(39)
Sqlquery = sSQL 
sFilePath = "C:\Temp\DataSheet.xlsx"

Dim objTempConnection : Set objTempConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim objTempRecordSet : Set objTempRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Dim strPath
'Define constants for objTempRecordset
Const adOpenStatic=3
Const adLockOptimistic=3
Const adLockPessimistic=2
Const adCmdText = &H001

'Open connection 
objTempConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="& sFilePath &";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"

objTempRecordset.ActiveConnection = objTempConnection
objTempRecordset.CursorType = adOpenStatic
objTempRecordset.LockType = adLockOptimistic 
objTempRecordset.Open Sqlquery 

If objTempRecordset.EOF Or objTempRecordset.BOF Then
    msgbox "no record"
End If

msgbox "Record Count: "&objTempRecordset.RecordCount

msgbox "Value:" & objTempRecordset.Fields.Item(0).Value
```

---

Comment: Just noticed that

**objTempRecordset.Fields.Item(0).Name**

returns **Expr1000**
and 

**objTempRecordset.Fields.Item("Expr1000").Value**

Returns correct value

However, I'm not sure what **Expr1000** means and how it is assigned. 

Not sure if it will change for different excel sheets, data, etc. hence need a way to define alias for columns so that I can retrieve data based on alias

Comment: Resolved: 

..."SELECT column_name **As [alias_name]** FROM..." in SQL solved the issue.

Thanks to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466225/expr1000-error-when-performing-a-sum-on-a-sql-query-in-excel

Comment: Are you sure `objTempRecordset.Fields.Item("RecCount").Value` didn't work as it should have if you used the first SQL query (not second one inside code block)? In first, you assigned a column alias *RecCount* but not in second which the ACE SQL engine assigns as the generic *Expr1000*.

Comment: As for you resolution, you DID do that in first SQL query!

Comment: That is right...
**objTempRecordset.Fields.Item("RecCount").Value** did not work because I had not used "Select Count(*) As **[** RowCount **]** FROM..." I had only used "Select Count(*) As RowCount FROM..." in the SQL query i.e. Alias should be mentioned between two square brackets in order to use it.

Comment: Not quite true. With the ACE engine, fields or table names with spaces, special chars, or reserved words need to be wrapped in square brackets (to escape them). Neither *RecCount* or *RowCount* have spaces, special chars, or are [reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe), so curious why it failed. Try these exact two (no spaces) again without brackets.

Comment: I think you are right! I tried RecCount/RowCount again without spaces and it worked!!. Not sure what I did wrong earlier. Yes, I figured that if alias had space in it then I should use [] however I was not trying it with spaces. Nevermind, great that it works. FYI, when I tried to fetch the results without alias i.e. using `SELECT Count(*) FROM...` and `objTempRecordset.Fields.Item("Count(*)").Value` it did not work (because of the special characters I presume)... that I why I was looking for the alias. You are right though. If alias does not have space it does not need [].

Comment: Thanks @Parfait !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the ACE SQL engine (used here in querying workbook), original field names, column aliases, or table names with spaces, special characters (non-alphanumeric), or [reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) need to be wrapped in **square brackets** or **backticks** to properly escape them.

**Spaces**

```
sSQL = "Select Count(*) AS [Rec Count] FROM [NELimits$] A" _
           & " WHERE A.Type = 'A' AND A.ID = 'R003'"
sSQL = "Select Count(*) AS `Rec Count` FROM [NELimits$] A" _
           & " WHERE A.Type = 'A' AND A.ID = 'R003'"
```

**Special Characters** (e.g., hyphen and pound/hashtag sign)

```
sSQL = "Select Count(*) AS [Rec-Count] FROM [NELimits$] A" _
           & " WHERE A.Type = 'A' AND A.ID = 'R003'"
sSQL = "Select Count(*) AS `Rec-Count` FROM [NELimits$] A" _
           & " WHERE A.Type = 'A' AND A.ID = 'R003'"

sSQL = "Select Count(*) AS [Rec#] FROM [NELimits$] A" _
           & " WHERE A.Type = 'A' AND A.ID = 'R003'"
sSQL = "Select Count(*) AS `Rec#` FROM [NELimits$] A" _
           & " WHERE A.Type = 'A' AND A.ID = 'R003'"
```

**Reserved words** (e.g., Count)

```
sSQL = "Select Count(*) AS [Count] FROM [NELimits$] A" _
           & "  WHERE A.Type = 'A' AND A.ID = 'R003'"
sSQL = "Select Count(*) AS `Count` FROM [NELimits$] A" _
           & " WHERE A.Type = 'A' AND A.ID = 'R003'"
```

Otherwise, any field name or column alias is legitimate in query and can be read in record set in following formats:

```
objTempRecordset.Fields.Item(0).Value               ' BY INDEX IN ITEM '
objTempRecordset.Fields.Item("Rec Count").Value     ' BY NAME IN ITEM '
objTempRecordset.Fields("Rec Count").Value          ' BY NAME IN FIELD COLLECTION '
objTempRecordset![Rec Count].Value                  ' BY NAME (EXCLAMATION POINT QUALIFIER) '
```

---

Furthermore, missing column aliases are handled in a special manner with ACE:

**Missing Alias on Query Expression** (e.g., Count function aggregation)

```
sSQL = "Select Count(*) FROM [NELimits$] A" _ 
           & " WHERE A.Type = 'A' AND A.ID = 'R003'"
```

**Missing Alias on Duplicate Field**

```
sSQL = "Select ID, ID FROM [NELimits$] A" _
           & " WHERE A.Type = 'A' AND A.ID = 'R003'"
```

For above two missing aliases, the ACE engine creates a column alias usually starting at *Expr1* (inside MS Access -the usual interface to the ACE Engine) or *Expr1000* for ODBC connections and incrementing for all other unnamed expressions or unnamed duplicate field references.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for detailed answer @Parfait